# TabSpec method to pass xmlResourceparser

Tags: android

I am using TabSpec to implement tabs and their navigation....I have 3 tabs ie Technology,Politics and Sports...I have created one class for each and one layout(xml file) for each..
  but .setIndicator  does not take (string,XmlResourceParse) as arguments...what method can I use?? 
my code of mainactivity is

```
package com.example.tabtest;

 import android.app.TabActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.res.Resources;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.widget.TabHost;
 import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

      public class TabTestMainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_test_main);

    Resources ressources = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

    //Technology tab
    Intent intentTech=new Intent().setClass(this,Technology.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecTech=tabHost
    .newTabSpec("Tech")         
    .setIndicator("",ressources.getLayout(R.layout.activity_technology)) //passing xml
                                                                               //  resourceParser
    .setContent(intentTech);   


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

   }
```

I searched other methods of TabSpec...but don't know which to implememt and how....

Comment: *what method can I use* - to do what exactly? Why would you want to pass a `XmlResourceParser` as an *indicator* to a tab? Semantically, that makes little sense. The indicator is basically the visual part of the actual tab view. Perhaps you should elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, so that we can help you better. It sounds like you should have already done the part that comes into play with the `XmlResourceParser` *before* you try to create the tabs.

Comment: @MH thanx... yup the command can't take xmlParse ..but can take drawable to set icons as tabs....But i want to set name of tab as "Technology"..what should i use....also i created a activity_technology.xml as the layout for Technology class and connected them by 'tools:context=".Technology" '  but the application crashes...I am new to android and java so sorry if i ask stupid questions.. :)

Comment: I think you may be confusing `setIndicator()` and `setContent()`. Use the latter to define the view (or `Intent` for the activity to start) and use `setIndicator()` for the tab text. The `Technology` activity that gets started with `intentTech` should take care of displaying `R.layout.activity_technology` etc.

Comment: Thanx @MH....so if i use setIndicator("technology"),and rest code remains same...shoul application be fine...coz it is crashing

Comment: @MH ...the application crashed coz TabActivity is deprecated....I"ll try implementing tabs using fragments.